# why is $log_n(\frac{k}{t})=-log_n(\frac{t}{k})$

Tags: logarithms

Why is $log_n(\frac{k}{t}) = -log_n(\frac{t}{k})$

for example, $log_3(15) = -log_3(1/15)$ (or any other base, t, or k)

I thought that it is because $log_3(15)$ is the same as $\frac{ln 15}{ln 3}$ and $log_3(1/15)$ is the same as $\frac{ln \frac{1}{15}}{ln 3}$ and $\frac{ln 15}{ln 3}$=$-\frac{ln \frac{1}{15}}{ln 3}$ multiply both sides by $ln3$ and we get $ln15 = -ln \frac{1}{15}$ but again I'm left with the original question since $ln$ is $log_e$.

Comment: $\log(a)+\log \left(\frac 1a\right)=\log \left(  a\times \frac 1a\right)=\log 1 =0$.  Or $\log a^{-1}=-1\times \log a$.

Comment: Or $$\log_b(\frac{1}{x})=\log_b(1)-\log_b(x)=-\log_b(x)$$

Comment: @Peter Thanks! yes, kind of the same idea! :D

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @lulu, I swapped sides so I get
$log_3(15) + log_3(1/15)=0$ and since $log(a)+log(b)$ is the same as $log(a*b)$ I can rewrite it as $log_3(15 * \frac{1}{15})$ which is basically $log_3(1)$ and $log_n(1) = 0$